# Illegal assignment from List<> to List<>

Tags: apex, soql

```
public class Sample 
{
public Quote quote{get;set;}
   
    public sample()
    {
        List<Quote> qu =[SELECT Id, Name FROM Quote];
    }
}
```

At line no. 7 I got "Illegal assignment from List to List" querry.
But When I replace Quote sObject to Account then it works fine how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely have a class or variable named "Quote", which is causing the problem, due to [Name Shadowing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_name_shadowing.htm). Use `Schema.Quote` instead:

```
public sample() {
    List<Schema.Quote> qu =[SELECT Id, Name FROM Quote];
}
```

You may want to refactor the Quote class; it's not ideal to use names that match standard objects, like Account and Quote, or standard libraries, like Test or Math.

Comment: Thanks It works :D