# Illegal assignment from List<User> to List<User>

Tags: soql, locale

I am trying to get the locales in use in my org and a user count for each locale to prepare for the spring update 22. However I am unable to run this SOQL to get this list.

I have looked for other answers and found [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/343400/illegal-assignment-from-list-to-list):
This thread did not help as this did not solve my issue.
I also tried [this thread](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000g1y6IAA):

I feel like it has something specific to do with this query

```
User[] usersUsingLocales = [SELECT toLabel(LocaleSidKey) LocaleName, LocaleSidKey, Count(id) UserCount FROM User where IsActive=true GROUP BY LocaleSidKey];
```

I would greatly appreciate if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong or is there is a better was to get the information I need I am all ears.

Comment: Pretty sure your title does not accurately reflect the contents of the error message.

Comment: Unforchunetly That error was copy and pasted here. That was the reason this started driving me crazy and why I posted here. I dont like to post bad questions on stack over flow but I had nothing else to turn to. That error message really needed to be more clear. If at any point it mentioned AggregateResult[] I would have been able to figure it out but all I got was Illegal assignment from List<User> to List<User>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing an aggregate query, but trying to assign the results to a list of Users.

Change User[] to AggregateResult[].
See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm

Comment: Thank you very much